# Bootstrap-UI - tooltip is still shown after alert

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have the following problem:

In my application every link has a tooltip (from bootstrap-ui). If the link is clicked, a alert dialog appears and the tooltip disappears. But in firefox the tooltip is still shown!

Here is a plunker:
[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DX9Vpuhrm4V4HEP7k7R2?p=preview)

And thats how I want to use it with tooltip:

```
<a tooltip="do something" tooltip-popup-delay="300" tooltip-placement="bottom" ng-click="doSomething()">do Something</a>
```

the function:

```
$scope.doSomething = function()
{
    alert("do Something");
}
```

After the alert window is confirmed, the tooltip is still shown in firefox.

Can someone help me, how to hide this tooltip in firefox? This is really stupid!

Thank you!

Comment: Show your code here, please.

Comment: One idea could be to simply hide any open tooltips, right after showing the alert, in the doSomething function.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually hide your tooltips by using jQuery like this:

```
jQuery('.tooltip').hide();
```

This will hide all instances of the tooltip.  In your case, you could call this right after your alert like so:

```
$scope.doSomething = function()
{
    alert("do Something");
    jQuery('.tooltip').hide();
}
```

Make sure you add the jQuery library if you go with this approach.

Comment: This is also the same approach I would use. However, I tried pasting it into the plunker that OP originally posted, and it didn't remove the tooltip after closing the alert. Did you verify that it works?

Comment: Yes, the plunker didn't have the jQuery library included.  You had to include that library for this to work.

Comment: is there a oppertunity to use this code without jquery?

Comment: Is your goal to keep jquery out of your project?

Comment: as long as it is possible ;-)

Comment: I think I also found a good solution: I changed the trigger: "'mouseenter': 'mouseleave'" to "'mouseenter': 'mouseleave blur'"

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: Did you use the $tooltipProvider to get it to work?  I can't get your mod to work.  If it works cross browser and follows the directive guidelines I don't see  problem with it. And no jQuery for you yet :)

Comment: exactly with the $tooltipProvider. Here is a new plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ws27WdeVypSkCfLOF6VH?p=preview I hope it will work in different browsers. My first tests in firefox, chrome and IE11 were successful :-)

Comment: im afraid, but even this method gives an error: $apply already in progress (You see it in the developer console). Any solutions for that? :(

Comment: I commented out your $tooltipProvider code in the config and was still getting the error.  I think there is something else going on unrelated to the $tooltipProvider setup.

Comment: Yeah that's right, very disappointing. Here is the issue on github: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/516